# Can we create a random uint8_ number using a simple casting?

Tags: c

In my compute, the function rand(); in C language outputs a 32-bit number.

Is the following code will generate a random uint_8 number? Or it can be platform-dependent?

```
uint8_t var=(uint8_t) rand();
```

I don't want to use modulo operation, due to time complexity of calculating modulo.

Comment: For regular, non-cryptographical uses, I think that will be approximately fine.

Comment: _"due to time complexity of calculating modulo"_ modulo should be rather fast, what is your platform? But anyway, what you're doing in your code s essentially a modulo 256 operation.

Comment: Make a call to `srand()` once in your code prior to calling.

Comment: @AKX Depends on what you mean by “regular” use. For anything that relies on a good distribution (fairly common in a lot of statistics and machine learning), this might give terrible results (it *might* also work fine, but I wouldn’t want to rely on that). Even for simulations/games, a low-quality generator can seriously skew the output. Of course using modulus would have the exact same issue (and using `rand` in general might).

Comment: This is very likely "pre-mature optimization". Unless you have benchmarked/disassembled code with modulo on your specific target system (which one is it), your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, using a better RNG will of course be, well, better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will indeed convert the return value of `rand` to a value of type `uint8_t`.  The conversion happens by essentially truncating all but the lowest order 8 bits.

As far as using the modulo operator, most compilers are smart enough to convert modulo by *2<sup>n</sup>* to a bitwise AND with a value with the *n* lower order bits set.

Note that for simple uses this is fine, however if you want to generate random numbers suitable for cryptographic purposes, or if you want to ensure better random distribution, you should use a crypto library such as OpenSSL instead of the `rand` function.

Comment: C lacks a _modulo operator_.  The similar remainder operator `%` does not use a simply bit mask to do `rand() % 256`, given sign is important, yet may still truncate all but the lowest order 8 bits for `uint8_t var=rand() % 256;`

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want to use modulo operation, due to time complexity of
> calculating modulo.

Modern compilers are smart enough to do not use division when it is not absolutely necessary.

All below result in the identical generated code:

```
uint8_t foo(void)
{
    return rand();
}

uint8_t foo1(void)
{
    return (uint8_t)rand();
}

uint8_t foo2(void)
{
    return rand() % 0x100;
}

uint8_t foo3(void)
{
    return rand() & 0xff;
}
```

And the generated code:

```
foo():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    rand
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
foo1():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    rand
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
foo2():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    rand
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
foo3():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    rand
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Answer (score -1):

If performance is key, this code would be the fastest way, cause it won't waste 3/4 of the `rand()` function.

PS `rand()` function is only guaranteed to return with a 16bit integer, so it might become problematic when your machine is not returning with a 32bit integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        /*
        typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) _fourbytes{
                uint8_t b0;
                uint8_t b1;
                uint8_t b2;
                uint8_t b3;
        } FOURBYTES;
        */

        typedef union __attribute__((packed)) _doubleword{
                /* FOURBYTES byte; */
                uint32_t dw;
                uint8_t byte[4];
        } DOUBLEWORD;

        DOUBLEWORD random_var;
        random_var.dw = rand();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                printf("random_var.byte[%d] = %d\n", i, random_var.byte[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has some problems.  The most serious one, for practical purposes, is that `rand()` always returns a positive signed integer, so the high byte will never be greater than 127.

Comment: I see, `rand()` returns `int` :-(. So maybe throw away the high byte, or just only use the lower 7bit of the highbyte.